# How to split a string on last occurrence of set a characters?

Tags: java, string, split

I have a text file which looks like this,

```
sku_id||01276116147620|L|
s_code||01276116|L|
s_prnt_prd||147620|L|
s_clr_fmly||White|L|
s_disp_clr||White|L|
s_size_desc||L|L|
s_status_str||Clearance|L|
s_ftr_cd||0|L|
```

Currently I read the whole thing to a buffered reader and create a single string. Then I use the split function to split the line on the "|L|" characters. This is all good until the line s_size_desc||L|L|. Here the split function doesn't work as expected. I want it to split it on the second occurrence of "|L|" in that line. How can I do this?

Comment: why do not you break on `newline`?

Comment: Is last occurrence of `"|L|"` always at the end of line?

Comment: Yes but the problem is I am reading line by line and appending it to one string. Then I pass that string to another function where it's split. So it's not actually line by line. The whole thing is one string like sku_id||01276116147620|L|s_code||01276116|L|s_size_desc||L|L|......

Comment: So you mean that real string doesn't have line separators?

Comment: Also can we know what is your goal? Do you need entire string in form you are having now? Can't you just create array without `|L|` while reading lines from your file and removing this `L` from them?

Answer (score 3):

1. Reverse string
2. Split on first occurrence of your delimiter string
3. Reverse string

Answer (score 0):

Remember if you sort/reverse etc. you have to count the cost of doing so.

But this is one possibility where you just replace the spurious |L| after splitting -

```
String st = "sku_id||01276116147620|L|s_code||01276116|L|s_prnt_prd||147620|L|s_clr_fmly||White|L|s_disp_clr||White|L|s_size_desc||L|L|s_status_str||Clearance|L|s_ftr_cd||0|L|";

        for(String ss : st.split("\\|L\\|")) {
            System.out.println(ss.replaceAll("L\\|", ""));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a greedy regular expression, i.e. one that will match as much text as possible. For example, in Extended Regular Expressions,

```
(L\\|)+
```

will match one or more occurrences of "L|", and will match as many as possible, including the second "L|" in your problematic line. So split your string on a regular expression like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this using a positive look behind which only use that `|L|` if it contains a character or number before,

```
String str="Your entire string";
str.split("(?<=\\w)\\|L\\|");
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `|L|` you want to split on is always at the end of line you can use

```
yourString.split("(?m)\\|L\\|$")
```

`(?m)` is regex multiline flag and it makes `^` and `$` anchors match start and end of lines (instead of start and end of entire string).

---

In case there are no lines separator other way to try would be checking if after `|L|` you split on there is no `L|` like

```
yourString.split("\\|L\\|(?!L\\|)")
```

---

Another solution would be creating your array without `|L|` while reading your data from file.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(yourFile));
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    int lastIndex = line.lastIndexOf("|L|");
    String lineWithoutL = line.substring(0,lastIndex);//do what you want with it
    System.out.println(lineWithoutL);
}
```